# MySQL load data ignoring lines - if (optionally) enclosed is set

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I would import one million rows from a CSV document to a database table.

To do this fast i use MySQL load data infile.

The problem is that everything works exactly great!
But there is a problem with lines which optionally enclosed by ".

**The CSV file.**

```
Name|Value\n
Anna|\n
Ben |Test\n
Chip|"My ""special"" value"\n
Deny|"I" like it\n
East|You not\n
```

**The MySQL command.**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv'
INTO TABLE `test`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
    IGNORE 1 LINES
(`name`, @value)
    SET
        `value` = nullif(@value, '')
;
```

**The result.**

```
Query OK, 4 rows affected, 1 warning (0.17 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1
```

**The warnings.**

```
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                    |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'value' at row 4 |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
```

**The table.**

```
+----+------+------------------------+
| id | name | value                  |
+----+------+------------------------+
|  1 | Anna | NULL                   |
|  2 | Ben  | Test                   |
|  3 | Chip | My "special" value     |
|  4 | Deny | "I" like it
East|You  |
+----+------+------------------------+
```

**How to solve?**

**Please note:**

My problem is not the warning!

If you see: The csv file contains 6 lines and 5 rows. (without header)
Also i need 5 rows/entries in mysql table. I have only 4 entries.

Comment: What is datatype and size of `value` column. If you give answer then you got solution.

Comment: `varchar[22]` - the longest line is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Your csv-file is invalid: Line 5 contains a `"`-char so (according to RFC-4180)

- the field has to be surrounded by double quotes and
- the quotes inside the field have to be repeatet

Using this you can successfully Import your csv by modifying it to

```
Name|Value
Anna|
Ben |Test
Chip|"My ""special"" value"
Deny|"""I"" like it"
East|You not
```

Answer (score -1):

This **Data truncated for column 'value' at row 4** warning message indicate that your field value is greater then your specified size. So you have to increase size of varchar to maximum length of your value.

Comment: and then? Whats with the 'East' entry? I have 4 rows in table and 5 in csv file.

Comment: Truncate your table like `truncate table test` and load csv file again

Comment: No. But look at the table result above please. The Problem is that mysql think if a " is after a | then the line must end with "... I think thats the problem.

Comment: I think that you have to debug one by one to put and remove quote from csv file. Might it will work

Comment: I added a information above. The problem is not the warning. http://i.imgur.com/EuF7Mg9.png